# -1 in a return (len(splits) - 1)?

Tags: python, string, count

The function should return the amount of times x appears in word. However, I need to make sure the function works even when x is multiple characters long.

**THIS IS NOT A SPECIFIC COUNT OF CHARS IN STRING QUESTION. IT IS ONLY ABOUT WHY THE -1 IS THERE**

My question is: Trying to understand use and meaning of "- 1" (LINE 6)

1 Original function:
2 
`3 def count_multi_char_x(word, x):
4     splits = word.split(x)
5     print(splits)
6     return (len(splits) - 1)
7`

What I've already tried:

and

Expected results:

```
print(count_multi_char_x("highlight", "igh"))
```

## print 2

```
print(count_multi_char_x("apple", "pp"))
```

## print 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

split returns a list of tokens from the word. So if you have babba then split('a') will go and return ['b', 'bb', ''] because 'a' appears at the end of the word.

use count() rather.

```
>>> a = 'babba'
>>> a.count('a')
2
>>> a.count('b')
3
```

Comment: I was just about to answer and then I saw your. We had the exact same idea :0

Comment: Thank you. But I understand what the split() function does so your example makes total sense. I just don't currently understand the use of -1. Does it mean that x takes up a certain value in the length of splits so when you subtract 1, you are essentially subtracting x out of the equation?

Comment: @progCoder_MT you're doing a len on the list that returns 6 cause there is 6 elements in the list. then -1 math is 5